# Запятая с двух сторон или с одной?

Tags: запятые

Можете, пленэры, мне сказать, нужна ли запятая та, которая мною выделена-таки?

Нужно ли ставить дефис после слова *диско*, и, следовательно, мои написания правильны-таки **(,)** или нужно ли-с такое слово писать вместе-таки, и, следовательно, я написал-таки всё по-плохому?

Comment: да нужно: нужно ли ставить тире, и следовательно(это союз, и поэтому) мои написания правильные, или нужно писать слитно. я юы исправил конец на "я написал-таки всё не так", плохое - это другое.

Comment: Рановато использовать "следовательно", ещё нет результата, чтобы что-то из чего-то следовало. Это не грамотно по стилистике.

Comment: "Или нужно ли-с" неверно. "Ли-с" лишнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, в этой части предложения: ‟Нужно ли ставить дефис после слова диско, и, следовательно, мои написания правильны-таки...” – нужно ставить запятую перед ‟и”, потому что здесь нет общих частей, здесь нет двух односоставных предложений, здесь нет обоих предложений с вопросительной интонацией, нет абсолютно никакой причины не ставить запятую.

Во-вторых, между предложениями: ‟следовательно, мои написания правильны-таки, или нужно ли-с такое слово писать вместе-таки” – нужно ставить запятую, потому что они не относятся друг к другу и уж тем более не могут иметь каких-то общих сочетаний.

В-третьих, такого правила точно не существует, что если есть некий блок, то нужно убрать законные запятые внутри блока, а между блоком поставить запятую и тире. Не надо придумывать на ходу правила, даже если интуиция подсказывает вам сделать это. Какую-то логику можно найти в этом, но должно быть **согласованное правило между людьми, написанное в учебнике по пунктуации**, иначе наоборот – это создаст ещё больше недопонимания, потому что люди будут думать, а почему это там нет запятой, придут на форум и будут спрашивать. Да, и в ссылке, которую вы только что добавили (Sharon), нет не только ни слова об убирании запятой, но там даже про запятую и тире нет ни слова, только про точку с запятой, и к тому же там написано, что внутренние знаки сохраняются.

> ...на стыке блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании...

В итоге: Нужно ли ставить дефис после слова диско, и, следовательно, мои написания правильны-таки, или нужно ли-с такое слово писать вместе-таки, и, следовательно, я написал-таки всё по-плохому?

И да, если хотите, то можете поставить точку с запятой перед ‟или”, она ставится, если автор хочет сделать предложение более удобным для восприятия и указать на границы каких-то блоков.

Comment: Точка с запятой в вопросах? Это слишком. Да и "или" связывает части, а точка с запятой разделяет, им не по пути.

Comment: Я не писал, что её нужно ставить, но её можно ставить везде, где есть какой-то блок.

Comment: Не везде. Когда союз, она не подходит.

Comment: В справочнике Розенталя есть глава про точку с запятой при сложносочинённой связи. Там, конечно же, много примеров с точкой запятой и союзом.

Comment: Там "или" нет, перед "или" не ставится. Это крайне тупо. Спрашивается, так или эдак. Вы же не напишете: *Так; или эдак?*

Comment: Я не вижу в этом ничего плохого,  и я не буду об этом спорить.

Answer (score 1):

О, выделенная запятая нужна, так что я бы даже единый знак(запятая и тире) поставила. Фразу надо разделить на два сообщения, иначе ваша мысль будет недостаточно ясно читаться. А вот две другие запятые я бы не стала ставить, опять по тем же причинам. Поэтому получится так:

*Нужно ли ставить дефис после слова *диско* и следовательно, мои написания правильны-таки, — **или** нужно ли-с такое слово писать вместе-таки и следовательно, я написал-таки всё по-плохому?*

**Правила, наверное, нужны?**

Здесь используется понятие **общего элемента** в сложной конструкции при выборе знаков, в частности влияние ЛИ...ИЛИ и вопросительной интонации. Союзное средство ЛИ...ИЛИ в сложных предложениях считается **повторяющимся** союзом, поэтому нет влияния общих элементов, как в случае одиночных союзов И/ИЛИ.

Кроме того, фраза делится на **смысловые блоки** (опять же в соответствии с правилами, § 132) http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136

**А что внутри блоков**?

Что там **с запятой перед И**?  Если поставить между блоками **запятую**, а внутри блоков будет тоже **запятая**, то прочитать и понять это сложно. Поэтому я убрала запятую перед И.

А вот если между блоками будет **единый знак** (или хотя бы тире, но лучше запятая и тире), то оставить запятую нужно по правилам, а ее отсутствие можно считать авторским вариантом. Мне очень хотелось оформить блоки  **как единое целое,** чтобы при чтении здесь не делали  **грамматическую** (подчеркнутую) паузу.

Comment: Ну так в "следовательно, мои написания правильны-таки" нет вопросительной интонации. Это просто следствие первого варианта. Единый знак не для разделения предложения на части, он используется при определённом взаимоотношении частей. При однородности его никак нельзя ставить. Ответ, к сожалению, полностью неверный.

Comment: К сожалению, это критика, что не соответствует правилам сайта.

Comment: Вы шутите? Вы же читали правила: "Когда стоит оставлять комментарий? Комментарий нужно оставить, если вы хотите: представить конструктивную **критику**, которая поможет автору улучшить сообщение" (https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Я не считаю вашу критику конструктивной. До свидания.

Comment: Конструктивная критика — это та, в которой указано, в чём проблема. *А вот две другие запятые я бы не стала ставить, опять по тем же причинам* — по каким причинам? Уточните ответ. Какой пункт правила там? Вопросительная интонация не во всех частях. Между однородными вещами ставить единый знак... Да уж. Почему ответ без правил? Потому что это им не соответствует.

Comment: И ещё раз: когда человек прав, можно с лёгкостью оправдаться.

Comment: Действительно, не надо придумывать правила на ходу. У вас не получается делать это с умом, как у Розенталя. Единый знак показывает отношения между частями (как двоеточие), не просто разделяет. Здесь нет подходящих отношений.